# Check if the element belongs to a vector and get its indices in R

Tags: r, vector, element

I want to know if an element belongs to a vector in R. I can do it with `%in%`, right? However, I also want to know the indices of all the examples of this element, and I want these indices as a vector as well. For example,

```
x<-c(1,3,5,5,7,5,8,9,0,5)

y< - myCoolFunction (x, 5)
```

y should be equal [3,4,6,10], because that's where 5 is in x.

I know how to do it **algorithm-wise** (with ifs and loops etc.), my questions is: is there an elegant R-style function to do it? Or a combination of two?

Comment: `??indices` will give you a list of commands that involve "indices", depending on what packages you have installed. As this is a rather basic functionality, look for `base::...` commands. There are two suggestions here, and one of them is `base::which`, as @PaulHiemstra answers. `??` is enormously helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which`:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,5,7,5,8,9,0,5)
which(x == 5)
# [1]  3  4  6 10
```

Or using `%in%` for multiple values:

```
which(x %in% c(1,3))
# [1] 1 2
```

And in a function:

```
myCoolFunction = function(vec, value) which(vec %in% value)
myCoolFunction(x, 5)
```

Although this essentially makes `myCoolFunction` an alias for `which` (with slightly different syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, you can also use `grep` for this, no quotes necessary.  However, it's much slower over large vectors.  Nice for short ones though...

```
> x <- c(1, 3, 5, 5, 7, 5, 8, 9, 0, 5)
> grep(5, x)
## [1]  3  4  6 10
```

Another variation to the `which` method uses `is.element`.  Might be easier to read.

```
> which(is.element(x, 5))
## [1]  3  4  6 10
```

Comment: Cool idea, +1. However, I would worry about (a) code readability (the next guy to come along and read my script will worry "why did he use `grep` and not `which`? What am I missing?") and (b) performance (on `x <- sample(x=1:10,size=1e7,replace=TRUE)`, the `which` approach took 0.17 seconds, the `grep` one took 3.98 seconds, a factor of 23).

Comment: Right, I hear ya.  Definitely not the best way since everything is coerced to another class, but I thought it was pretty neat when I found it.  I was going to point out that `is.element` can go along with `which` for (possibly) better readability (i.e. `which(is.element(x, 5))` )